# Numpy comparing vectors of length m and n resulting in boolean matrix of size m,n

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to run the comparison (or really many other functions) using numpy.

```
a = np.array([1,2,5,7])
b = np.array([0,4,6])

np.repeat(a, len(b)).reshape(-1, len(b)) > b

> array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Basically each output (m, n) is the comparison if `A_m` > `B_n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **broadcasting** to make this operation more efficient. Indeed, `repeat` creates a new temporary array. Here is the resulting code:

```py
a.reshape(-1, 1) > b
```

Comment: `A[:, None]` is a common alternative

Comment: Can you cast with higher dimensions, say `a` has length `m` but now `b` has size `n, o`

Comment: For others who might stumble across this I did something like this `a[:, None, None] > b[None, :, :]`